# "Главное в этом деле – не переборщить". Должно ли здесь стоять тире перед сказуемым?

Tags: пунктуация

С одной стороны, перед сказуемым стоит отрицание "не", с другой – для правильной передачи смысла требуется тире. Запуталась.

Answer (score 1):

Тире нужно.

> С одной стороны, перед сказуемым стоит отрицание "не"

Такое правило действительно существует, но имеет силу тогда и только тогда, когда подлежащее и сказуемое выражены существительным, местоимением или числительным в именительном падеже. В этом случае тире перед сказуемым с отрицанием не является необходимым (но изредка может ставиться как интонационное). У нас сказуемое выражено инфинитивом глагола. Тире ставится по общему правилу.

> с другой – для правильной передачи смысла требуется тире. Запуталась.

Ну такая формулировка сама по себе очень странной выглядит. Что значит "для передачи смысла"? Есть то самое правило, что тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым:

> Тире ставится если... подлежащее и сказуемое выражены инфинитивами или
>   один из них – инфинитив, а другой – существительное (числительное) в
>   именительном падеже.

Ему и надо следовать.

Подробнее - тут https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/706-17_tire_mezhdu_podlezhaschim_i_skazuemym.html

Ну или в любом справочнике.

(+)
Группа подлежащего у нас: "Главное в этом деле". Несмотря на то, что здесь много слов, существенным является то, что "Главное" выступает в роли существительного в именительном падеже.

Comment: "Для передачи смысла" имела в виду, что предложение можно прочитать (и понять) по разному. Или "Главное В ЭТОМ ДЕЛЕ не переборщить" или "Главное в этом деле НЕ ПЕРЕБОРЩИТЬ".

Comment: Я понял. Но это ошибочное представление. Дважды. Во-первых, что тут есть какая-то двусмысленность, во-вторых, что двусмысленность вообще может сниматься с помощью эллиптического тире.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно тире.

Тире ставится, если можно вставить слово "это". В таких случаях пропущен глагол "являться" и место сказуемого заменяет часть речи после тире.
*Главным в этом деле **является** то, чтобы не переборщить.

Главное в этом деле – (это) не переборщить.*

Comment: Где вы такое правило нашли?

Comment: Перед словом "это" тире ставится - общеизвестный факт. А без "это" особо ничего и не меняется, ведь глагол пропущен.